# Savon::SOAPFault: (p448:B2BServiceException) com.uhg.ut.ues.b2b.services.B2BServiceException: An Active HTTP Session does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, soapui, savon

I am working on an application and facing this issue.

```
Savon::SOAPFault: (p448:B2BServiceException) com.uhg.ut.ues.b2b.services.B2BServiceException: An Active HTTP Session does not exist
from /Users/ankits4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@business-tool/gems/savon-2.12.0/lib/savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!'
```

can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

`Savon::SOAPFault` is an exception raised when the response from the service contains:
- `Fault>`
- and `faultcode>` with `faultstring>` or `Code>` with `Reason>`

Source: [.present? method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/savon/Savon/SOAPFault)

In your case, service raised an error with the following description:

```
An Active HTTP Session does not exist
```

I think you have to check in the service documentation what does it mean.